# PyScript: running code blocks in between paragraphs in HTML?

Tags: python, html, pyscript, pyodide

I've been looking for a way to run interactive python code blocks on my personal website, and PyScript looked to be a good solution. However, it seems like PyScript is currently designed to always output at the end of HTML  tags, rather than in between sections of HTML code.

```html
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
<div>   
    <div>
    <py-env>
        <py-script src="indexcode.py" std-out="output">
        </py-script>
    </py-env>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>

<p>This is a block of HTML</p>
```

In the code above, I tried to define a separate  tag to take the output of my PyScript code using the std-out attribute, but this doesn't seem to affect the position of the output, (where the code is outputted, *then* the "This is a block of HTML" section follows.)

[Screenshot of resulting code on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1qYV.png)

I'm wondering if there's any good solution to this? None of the examples on PyScript's website had anything close to this. I understand that PyScript's relatively new, so it's possible that this just isn't a feature yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyScript introduces a new "built-in" function (i.e. a function you do not need to import) called [display()](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/API/display.html) for this use case, of sending text content to the page. `display()` takes an optional keyword argument called `target`, which specifies the ID of a DOM element to write the content to. If `target` is not specified, the content appears as a child element of the current <py-script> (or <py-repl>) tag.

```html
<div id="verytop"></div>

<p>AAA</p>

<py-script>
    display("One")
</py-script>

<p>BBB</p>

<py-script>
    display("Two")
</py-script>

<p>CCC</p>

<py-script>
    display("Up Top", target="verytop")
</py-script>
```

The output order is then:

```
Up Top
AAA
One
BBB
Two
CCC
```